# Grafana helm chart with PostgreSQL instead of SQLite 3 - How to hide the database credentials

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana, mozilla-sops

I'm using Grafana with Helm https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/grafana. I would like to switch from SQLite 3 to PostgreSQL as my backend database. However, I'm concerned about the security of my database credentials, which are currently stored in the values.yaml file as plain text.

What is the recommended way to switch to PostgreSQL and hide the database credentials in a secure way? Can I use Kubernetes secrets or some other mechanism to achieve this? (Please I need to know where, in the values.yaml file, I have to do the configuration)

I'm connecting Grafana with the PostgreSQL database inside the grafana.ini section in the values.yaml, E.g.:

```
grafana.ini:
  database:
    type: "postgres"
    host: "db.postgres.database.azure.com"
    name: "grafana-db"
    user: "grafana-db-user"
    password: ""grafana-db-pass"
    ssl_mode: "require"
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

I've tried to include use the env section but it's not working.

Comment: Had you already seen this section from your link? [How to securely reference secrets in grafana.ini](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/grafana#how-to-securely-reference-secrets-in-grafanaini)

Comment: @jordanm thank you so much. I hadn't seen this section of the chart documentation, you saved my life. Now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Had you already seen this section from your link? How to securely reference secrets in grafana.ini –
> jordanm

Thank you so much @jordanm :)